# Extracting text from JSON variable between two strings when second string occurs more than once

Tags: json, sql-server, rest

I have a wall of text that is created from a JSON set of data. I need to extract a string that occurs inside this wall of text.

Wall of text (stored as variable `@name`)

```
"re_id":110482,"username":"John Smith",
```

I need to extract just John Smith from this string. I have used the many answers available here to answer this, however the problem is ", appears more than once in the variable. Is there an easy way to `CHARINDEX` this out to just John Smith?

It should also be noted, this is SQL Server 2016, however I am unable to use DECLARE because of the proprietary ITIL application we are inputing this into.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('#[VAR.all]#', CHARINDEX('""username":"', '#[VAR.all]#'), CHARINDEX('",','#[VAR.all]#') - CHARINDEX('""username":"', '#[VAR.all]#') + Len(1))  as var
```

What I get as a result is: `"username":"John Smith"` where I want just John Smith (no quotes)

Again, I cannot use the DECLARE function or any JSON queries.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

if @name represents the wall of text you provided in your additional comment, the following change should work (except perhaps field4 needs to become username):

```
select substring(@name, CHARINDEX(':', @name, CHARINDEX('field4', @name)) + 2, len(@name) - CHARINDEX(':', @name, CHARINDEX('field4', @name)) - 2)
```

Comment: this just results in username. The source data will look like "field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"value3","field4":"value4" I need to return the value of value4 by selecting only what appears after field4. Does that makes sense? I apologize, I've been working many hours lately trying to push this into our proprietary system. If I had full access to the JSON data and not just a text output of it, I wouldn't have any issues creating variables with SQL JSON queries...

Comment: i have adjusted based on your new information in your comment